# Possible reasons why (apparently) identical GET could fail in soapUI while working in PostMan

Tags: rest, get, postman, soapui

We are trying to set up an api interface between two web-applications. When testing the GET call, it works from PostMan while not working from soapUI. The web-apps seems to be failing like soapUI.

I am hoping that if we can identify and understand the difference, we can resolve the issue.

Some info:

1. Both use Basic Authentication with a username and password (they both seem to be allowed access, as authenticated POST calls work from both testing tools).
2. From neither of the tools do we pass any parameter explicitly. It's a static URL we are calling to. However, the URL does include a resource-id (a target report) that could be set up as a template parameter if we wanted to.
3. When making the call from soapUI, the log on the application that is supposed to respond to the GET says `javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"reportExecution")`.
4. The call we use is something like `GET [endpoint]/jasperserver-pro/rest_v2/reportExecutions/0cc3aefc-29b6-45b1-8248-ae4e1457bb87/status`

Update: By now I am quite sure this has to do with cookies. The request id `0cc3aefc-29b6-45b1-8248-ae4e1457bb87` above was received in a previous call and you need to to request the status with the same access token, which you can do with Cookies, but setting that up in soapUI is no simple matter (at least not for me). In PostMan this seems to be the standard behaviour, and hence the difference in result.

Best regards

Pieka

Comment: hi, have you set any header ? could you show the raw request from Postman and from SOAPUI ?

Comment: Here is SOAP `Thu Jan 16 13:35:02 CET 2020:DEBUG:Sending request: GET /jasperserver-pro/rest_v2/reportExecutions/02e399e1-b5c3-4e3f-8aca-7918c1f12abf/status HTTP/1.1` and the PostMan is `.../jasperserver-pro/rest_v2/reportExecutions/2ad79ce2-69e4-4240-a026-f40c279597ef/status` (I know these are not identical. )
`

Comment: Well, that's not complete enough. Could you, in both tools, point to the request itself then you should find different tabs lableled 'request', 'raw', 'outline', etc. From the 'raw' tab you should be able to extract additional data such as headers, tokens, etc. Please edit and update your post when you have this information

Comment: In SoapUI, do you have "Maintain HTTP Session" checked? https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/testing/cookies.html